# When should I use Popen() and when should I use call()?

Tags: python, call, subprocess, popen

Caveat: new to Python.

Wanting to hear from professionals who actually use it:

**What are the main differences between `subprocess.Popen()` and `subprocess.call()` and when is it best to use each one?**

Unless you want to read why I was thinking about this question or what to center your answer around, you may stop reading now.

I was inspired to ask this question because I am working through an issue in a script where I started using `subprocess.Popen()`, eventually called a system pause, and then wanted to delete the .exe that created the system pause, but I noticed with `Popen()`, the commands all seemed to run together (the delete on the .exe gets executed before the exe is closed..), though I tried adding `communicate()`.

Here is fake code for what I'm describing above:

```
subprocess.Popen(r'type pause.exe > c:\worker.exe', shell=True).communicate()
subprocess.Popen(r'c:\worker.exe', shell=True).communicate()
subprocess.Popen(r'del c:\worker.exe', shell=True).communicate()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> subprocess.call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
>   Run command with arguments. Wait for
>   command to complete, then return the
>   returncode attribute.

If you create a `Popen` object, you must call the `sp.wait()` yourself.

If you use `call`, that's done for you.